# In C++, is there any reason to spawn and immediately join a thread, instead of just calling the function directly?

Tags: c++, multithreading

In C++, is there any reason someone would want to write

```
std::thread t(foo);
t.join();
```

versus

```
foo();
```

?

It seems to me like the first option just uses more resources to create a thread for no reason, but am I missing something?

Comment: Seems pointless to me, too, for what it's worth.

Comment: Maybe can be interrupted the thread that can execute foo function.

Comment: It would get its own copy of `thread_local` variables.  Maybe that could be useful in some remote edge case.

Comment: All in all hard to tell without seeing what is covered by `foo()`.

Comment: In general no. Otherwise people would be already be writing their programs like this, and if that were the case, I'd contend that you have a problem with the language.

Comment: Where did you encounter this code? Perhaps there’s some surrounding context that would make this worthwhile?

Comment: In general, no.  But there are unique scenarios, especially with Win32 code, where you don't want the code being run to interfere with the state of the current thread. (For example, a Win32 or COM code that pumps messages). Hence, just getting that code to run in its own thread is sometimes needed even when the semantics just want synchronous behavior.

Answer (score 5):

In C++ proper, only because you want fresh new thread local state, then dispose of it.   Probably a bad desogn.

Outside of C++ proper, in some execution environments code behaves differently in the main thread than outside of it.

That ensures the code doesn't run in the main, often UI, thread, while still ensuring it is blocking and synchronous.

A practical bent might be running some task which messes with its own thread state in ways you don't trust, nor know how to fully reverse.  Ie, a third party library.  This is basically the first case, but you are trying to save yourself from bad code you cannot rewrite.

Comment: Related to thread state, it might be worth mentioning that a new thread gets a new stack. We're on Stack Overflow after all...